# Icon shape and placement issue in Files application after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, icons, gui, layout

After upgrading to 18.04 icon's/folder's/document's shape and font have some problem. There is some extra gap on the right side of screen. Resizing doesn't help either.
Below is the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's an issue with displaying icons in the file manager application (Nautilus) in older releases. It's much more improved in later releases, e.g. 20.04, see here ('*Dynamic resizing*' section): https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/nautilus-3-30-improvements-new-path-bar